# Sentiment analysis of news articles using word2vec

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, word2vec

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to create a sentiment analysis of news articles from german news outlets (rougly 60.000 articles from 9 different sites) using word2vec.

My current approach is:

- dumping the articles' text into a file (one per news outlet)
- feeding the resulting text corpus to the model (one per news outlet) → word vectors
- using a data set of positive/negative german words with a weight between -1 and 1 indicating the sentiment to create a "sentiment score" for words in articles by using the similarity function that gensim.word2vec provides
- creating an average score for a number of news articles that are not included in the training data

Now the problem is that I am not sure which words I should select for the analysis. I could either use every word in the article or maybe just filter relevant words and then create the scores.

Do you think this a valid/good approach? Do you maybe have any idea what a better approach would be?

Comment: You probably want to do at least some initial filtering like removing stopwords such as the German equivalent of 'in', 'and', 'the', etc if you're not doing this already.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that. I already filter stopwords, yes.

Comment: This is a little broad for SO. But one thing to consider when doing sentiment analysis is that word order matters. For example: ‘the meal was good’ and ‘the meal was not good’ have almost opposite sentiments and that’s hard to capture by scoring individual words. A better approach might be to use word embeddings in addition to a sequence model like LSTM for this sort of problem.